# Elegant alternative for updating specific database table columns without using ORM

Tags: java, c#

I have a repository class:

```
public class IRepository {

    ...
    User FindUser(int id);

    ...

    bool UpdateUser(User user);

    ...
}
```

I have a service class:

```
public class Service {

    ...

    public bool ChangePassword(...) {
        User user = repository.FindUser(...);
        user.PasswordHash = ...;
        return repository.UpdateUser(user);
    }

    ...
}
```

I am not using Entity Framework or any other ORMs.  So, the most optimized way is to create and call one method that updates the table in one statement:

```
UPDATE user SET password_hash = ... WHERE ...
```

My question is: In order to maintain the whole concept of the repository pattern, does it make sense for me to introduce a new method:

```
bool UpdatePassword(int id, string passwordHash);
```

into the repository class or is there a more elegant solution that takes into account that future versions may use an ORM?

Comment: First of all, I strongly recommend that you use an ORM. Now for your question: Instead of adding `UpdatePassword` to repository, you should add this method to service layer. As an embodiment of [Single Responsibility principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle), repository class shouldn't contain business logic.

Comment: @raidensan My service layer has a ChangePassword while the Repository has an UpdatePassword.  If I removed the latter, how should I obtain my desired outcome without using an ORM, which is something I need time to learn?

Comment: Are `ChangePassword` and `UpdatePassword` doing the same thing? Is sure sounds like they do.

Comment: @raidensan The former does the business logic whereas the latter simply does an UPDATE statement.

Comment: If you want your code to be *ORM Ready*, my comment still applies. You should modify `User`  object instance -change password, change name etc.- at service layer and call `UpdateUser` in repository with modified version of object. Of course this will introduce handling update manually without ORM which is a tedious and error-prone task. Invest some time in learning ORM, it will save you from a lot of trouble.

Comment: @raidensan But the question is besides the UpdateUser(User) in the repository, what name should I use for the method because putting UpdatePassword(User, password) there does not make sense.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179163/discussion-between-raidensan-and-lisa-kot).